# Webpack does not see the absolute path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I use absolute paths in my React application. But the WebPack throws me a error. `ERROR in ./src/index.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'App' in .../client/src'` However, my file is located in this folder. How to solve this problem? I saw that I already wrote about similar problems, but I did not find the answer in them

WebPack config

```
    const path = require('path');
    const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
    const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

    module.exports = {
        entry: './src/index.js',
        output: {
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
            publicPath: '/',
            filename: 'bundle.js'
        },
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader'
                },
                {
                    test: /\.css$/, use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
                }
                ]
        },
        plugins: [
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                filename: 'index.html',
                template: './public/index/html'
            }),
            new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
                filename: 'style.css'
            })
        ]
    };
```

Hierarchy of my files

```
---project
      --client
         -public
           index.html
         -src
           'folders'
           index.js
           App.js
           App.css
      --package.json
      --webpack.config.js
      --.babelrc
```

Comment: Could you post the explorer of your project?

Comment: Are you using create-react-app?

Comment: No, without CRA

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add this to your webpack.config file.

```
 resolve: {
      extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
      alias: {
        root: __dirname,
        src: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
      },
    },
```

Then you can import by

`import something from 'src/index.js'`

But if you use something else than Webpack, e.g. Jest, Storybook then you would also need to apply that information.

E.g. for Jest

`npm install babel-plugin-module-resolver`

and update `.babelrc` to understand absolute path

```
{
  "plugins": [
    [
      "module-resolver",
      {
        "extensions": [".js", ".jsx"],
        "root": ["./src"],
        "alias": {
          "root": ".",
          "src": "/src"
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```